# How to enable VI key binding in cmder?

Tags: windows, conemu, vi, cmder

In linux terminal we can easily enable vi key-binding mode with commands like `set -o vi`. Does cmder on windows provide any such feature? Or Is there any hack available to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this answer, there is currently no way to do this. Consider giving [this relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1577) requesting support for this a thumbs up.